# Let $ϕ$ be the Euler phi-function . Let $p$ and $q$ two different prime numbers. Prove that $p | ϕ(q^p) − ϕ(q)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ϕ$  be the Euler phi-function . Let $p$ and $q$ two different prime numbers.

Prove that $p$ divides $ϕ(q^p) − ϕ(q)$. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\text{As }q\text{ is prime }\phi(q^p)=q^{p-1}(q-1)$$

$$\text{So, }\phi(q^p)-\phi(q)=q^{p-1}(q-1)-(q-1)=(q-1)(q^{p-1}-1)$$

Use [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html)